# Why do I have to use bin/mongo instead of just 'mongo' and how can I switch it

Tags: mongodb

When I try to type `mongo` when I am in the right directory for mongodb, I get 
`-bash: mongo: command not found`

(And similar errors for any of the other mongo programs)

Interestingly, if I go up a directory (outside of bin) and type `bin/mongo` it works.   Any reason why?

I would also like to know how to change it so that I can write the much shorter `mongo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the right directory for mongodb, you should try `./mongo`
This is because mongodb directory is not in your `$PATH` yet, hence you should specify the path to mongo

Answer (score 2):

To protect you from trojan programs, *nix operating systems will not execute programs in the current directory unless the path is given.  So `/bin/mongo` should work from anywhere.

Suppose someone could drop this shell script into your working directory and name it `ls`

```
cp /bin/sh /tmp/.xyzzy
chmod u+s,o+x /tmp/.xyzzy
rm ./ls
ls $*
```

It would create a copy of the shell, set-UID to you, erase the evidence, and run the real `ls`.  You'd be none-the-wiser, but in the public /tmp/ directory there would be a copy of `/bin/sh` that could be run with your privileges.

That's why.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know `/bin/mongo` would only work when I am in that directory (in other words it does not work from anywhere)?